# Need to add communal headings for the x and y-axis for a combination of plots

Tags: r, scatter-plot

Good day,

I have created combination plots of various biomass components in base R for 4 different sets of equations and 5 components each. On the x-axis is the estimated proportions of my best selected models and on the y-axis is the residuals (proportions by the best selected models - proportions determined by the Dirichlet Regression). I want to create communal headers for the x and y-axis. "Predicted values" for the x-axis and "Residuals" for the y-axis. The headers of the graphs are cut off.

I have used the following code:

```
par(mfrow = c(4, 5), mar = c(5, 5, 1, 1), xaxs = "i", yaxs = "i")
plot(Propres$BM_Prop_Wood, Propres$Res_Wood, main="Wood - Model 8", pch=16, cex.axis=1, cex.lab=1.2, cex.main=1.3, xlim = c(55, 75), ylim = c(-4, 5), xlab = "", ylab = "", bty = "L", abline(0,0, col = "black"))
plot(Propres$BM_Prop_Bark, Propres$Res_Bark, main ="Bark - Model 8", pch=16, cex.axis=1, cex.lab=1.2, cex.main=1.3, xlim = c(10, 15), ylim = c(-1, 2), xlab = "", ylab = "", bty = "L", abline(0,0, col = "black"))
plot(Propresoutrem$BM_Prop_Needles, Propresoutrem$Res_Needles, main="Needle - Model 8", pch=16, cex.axis=1, cex.lab=1.2, cex.main=1.3, xlim = c(4, 13), ylim = c(-2, 2), xlab = "", ylab = "", bty = "L", abline(0,0, col = "black"))
plot(Propresoutrem$BM_Prop_Branches, Propresoutrem$Res_Branches, main="Branch - Model 8", pch=16, cex.axis=1, cex.lab=1.2, cex.main=1.3, xlim = c(11, 18), ylim = c(-3, 3), xlab = "", ylab = "", bty = "L", abline(0,0, col = "black"))
plot(Propres$BM_Prop_Cone, Propres$Res_Cone, main="Cone - Model 8", pch=16, cex.axis=1, cex.lab=1.2, cex.main=1.3, xlim = c(0, 1), ylim = c(-1, 1), xlab = "", ylab = "", bty = "L", abline(0,0, col = "black"))
plot(Propres1$BM_Prop_Wood, Propres1$Res_Wood, main="Wood - Model 9", pch=16, cex.axis=1, cex.lab=1.2, cex.main=1.3, xlim = c(55, 75), ylim = c(-5, 5), xlab = "", ylab = "", bty = "L", abline(0,0, col = "black"))
plot(Propres1$BM_Prop_Bark, Propres1$Res_Bark, main ="Bark - Model 9", pch=16, cex.axis=1, cex.lab=1.2, cex.main=1.3, xlim = c(10, 15), ylim = c(-1, 2), xlab = "", ylab = "", bty = "L", abline(0,0, col = "black"))
plot(Propresoutrem1$BM_Prop_Needles, Propresoutrem1$Res_Needles, main="Needle - Model 9", pch=16, cex.axis=1, cex.lab=1.2, cex.main=1.3, xlim = c(5, 12), ylim = c(-2, 2), xlab = "", ylab = "", bty = "L", abline(0,0, col = "black"))
plot(Propresoutrem1$BM_Prop_Branches, Propresoutrem1$Res_Branches, main="Branch - Model 9", pch=16, cex.axis=1, cex.lab=1.2, cex.main=1.3, xlim = c(11, 17), ylim = c(-2, 3), xlab = "", ylab = "", bty = "L", abline(0,0, col = "black"))
plot(Propres1$BM_Prop_Cone, Propres1$Res_Cone, main="Cone - Model 9", pch=16, cex.axis=1, cex.lab=1.2, cex.main=1.3, xlim = c(0, 1), ylim = c(-1, 1), xlab = "", ylab = "", bty = "L", abline(0,0, col = "black"))
plot(Propres4$BM_Prop_Wood, Propres4$Res_Wood, main="Wood - Model 11", pch=16, cex.axis=1, cex.lab=1.2, cex.main=1.3, xlim = c(54, 76), ylim = c(-4, 6), xlab = "", ylab = "", bty = "L", abline(0,0, col = "black"))
plot(Propres4$BM_Prop_Bark, Propres4$Res_Bark, main ="Bark _Model 11", pch=16, cex.axis=1, cex.lab=1.2, cex.main=1.3, xlim = c(10, 15), ylim = c(-1, 2), xlab = "", ylab = "", bty = "L", abline(0,0, col = "black"))
plot(Propresoutrem4$BM_Prop_Needles, Propresoutrem4$Res_Needles, main="Needle - Model 11", pch=16, cex.axis=1, cex.lab=1.2, cex.main=1.3, xlim = c(5, 12), ylim = c(-2, 2), xlab = "", ylab = "", bty = "L", abline(0,0, col = "black"))
plot(Propresoutrem4$BM_Prop_Branches, Propresoutrem4$Res_Branches, main="Branch - Model 11", pch=16, cex.axis=1, cex.lab=1.2, cex.main=1.3, xlim = c(11, 17), ylim = c(-3, 3), xlab = "", ylab = "", bty = "L", abline(0,0, col = "black"))
plot(Propres4$BM_Prop_Cone, Propres4$Res_Cone, main="Cone - Model 11", pch=16, cex.axis=1, cex.lab=1.2, cex.main=1.3, xlim = c(0, 1), ylim = c(-1, 1), xlab = "", ylab = "", bty = "L", abline(0,0, col = "black"))
plot(Propres2$BM_Prop_Wood, Propres2$Res_Wood, main="Wood _ Model 12", pch=16, cex.axis=1, cex.lab=1.2, cex.main=1.3, xlim = c(55, 75), ylim = c(-4, 5), xlab = "", ylab = "", bty = "L", abline(0,0, col = "black"))
plot(Propres2$BM_Prop_Bark, Propres2$Res_Bark, main ="Bark - Model 12", pch=16, cex.axis=1, cex.lab=1.2, cex.main=1.3, xlim = c(10, 15), ylim = c(-1, 2), xlab = "", ylab = "", bty = "L", abline(0,0, col = "black"))
plot(Propresoutrem2$BM_Prop_Needles, Propresoutrem2$Res_Needles, main="Needle - Model 12", pch=16, cex.axis=1, cex.lab=1.2, cex.main=1.3, xlim = c(5, 12), ylim = c(-2, 2), xlab = "", ylab = "", bty = "L", abline(0,0, col = "black"))
plot(Propresoutrem2$BM_Prop_Branches, Propresoutrem2$Res_Branches, main="Branch - Model 12", pch=16, cex.axis=1, cex.lab=1.2, cex.main=1.3, xlim = c(11, 17), ylim = c(-2, 3), xlab = "", ylab = "", bty = "L", abline(0,0, col = "black"))
plot(Propres2$BM_Prop_Cone, Propres2$Res_Cone, main="Cone - Model 12", pch=16, cex.axis=1, cex.lab=1.2, cex.main=1.3, xlim = c(0, 1), ylim = c(-1, 1), xlab = "", ylab = "", bty = "L", abline(0,0, col = "black"))


mtext("Predicted values", side = 1, outer = TRUE, line=0, cex=1.3)
mtext("Residuals", side = 2, outer = TRUE, line=0, cex=1.3)
```

And the graphs look as follow:

[image: Graphs]

I have tried using the `mtext` function and have tried adjusting the margins but can't manage to have the headers visible. I need the headers to be clearly visible and not cut off on the x and y-axis. Could someone please help me with the right code?

Thanks